If $G = \langle A\mid R\rangle$ and $G' = \langle A'\mid R'\rangle$ are group presentations then $\langle A\cup A'\mid R\cup R'\rangle$ is a coproduct
This is problem II.8.7 from Aluffi's algebra textbook. It's been asked a couple times on this website, but I feel unsatisfied by the answers. I will state the question, show my current work, then explain why I am confused.
The questions considers $G = \langle A\mid R\rangle$ and $G' = \langle A'\mid R'\rangle$ to be group presentations, with $A\cap A' = \varnothing$, and asks use to show that group $G\ast G'$ presented by $\langle A\cup A'\mid R\cup R'\rangle$ satisfies the universal property for the coproduct of $G$ and $G'$ in the category $\textbf{Grp}$.
I start by constructing natural homomorphisms from $G\to G\ast G'$ and $G'\to G\ast G'$.
For $G\to G\ast G'$, consider the set map $f:A\to G\ast G'$ which sets $f(a) = a\langle\langle R\cup R'\rangle\rangle$. Notice I emphasize the coset structure of $G\ast G'\cong F(A\cup A')/\langle\langle R\cup R'\rangle\rangle$. Letting $\iota: A\to F(A)$ be the canonical map, there exists a unique homomorphism $\varphi_G: F(A)\to G\ast G'$ such that $f = \varphi_G\circ\iota$.
Next, we notice that $\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle\subseteq \ker\varphi_G$, so that their exists a unique homomorphism $\sigma_G: F(A)/\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle\to G\ast G'$ such that $\sigma_G\circ\pi_G = \varphi_G$ where $\pi_G$ is the canonical quotient map $F(A)\to F(A)/\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle$. Since $G\cong F(A)/\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle$, $\sigma_G: G\to G\ast G'$ is the desired homomorphism.
Doing the same process for $G'$ we get a homomorphism $\sigma_{G'}\to G\ast G'$.
Notice an element of $G$, that is a coset $w\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle$, gets mapped $\sigma_G(w\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle) = w\langle\langle R\cup R'\rangle\rangle$
Now, given arbitrary group homomorphisms $\psi : G\to Z$ and $\psi': G'\to Z$ we want to show that there exists a unique homomorphism $\Phi: G\ast G' \to Z$ such that $\psi = \Phi\circ\sigma_G$ and $\psi' = \Phi\circ\sigma_H$.
The only real sensible way to do this is to define:
$\Phi(a\langle\langle R\cup R'\rangle\rangle)\to \psi(a\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle)$ if $a \in A$
$\Phi(a'\langle\langle R\cup R'\rangle\rangle)\to \psi'(a'\langle\langle R'\rangle\rangle)$ if $a' \in A'$.
If $\Phi$ is well-defined, it automatically becomes a homomorphism. This is where I'm having trouble. I get confused because I want to say that it's impossible for $a\langle\langle R\cup R'\rangle\rangle = a'\langle\langle R\cup R'\rangle\rangle$ if $a\in A$ and $a'\in A'$, but my interpretation of these groups as quotient groups obscures it.
I have seen other solutions on this website which say that since $\psi$ is determined by where it maps $A$ the generators of $G$, ditto for $\psi'$, that we can just define $\Phi(a) = \psi(a)$ for $a\in A$ and $\Phi(a')=\psi'(a')$ for $a'\in A'$, but I feel like this doesn't take into consideration the fact that $a$ is not simply a letter in $G\ast G'$ but actually a coset. Should I abandon my viewing these groups as cosets? If I forego this rigorous treatment I can see how everything works out, but I want to make it rigorous :(
Many thanks for your help.

I don't really understand your problem, but your claim that $a\langle\langle R \cap R'\rangle\rangle = a'\langle\langle R \cap R'\rangle\rangle $ is impossible would not be true if $a \in \langle\langle R \rangle\rangle$ and $a'\in \langle\langle R' \rangle\rangle$.

For a formal treatment, the generators of a group defined by a presentation $G = \langle A \mid R \rangle$ are not elements of $G$, they are just elements of a set $A$, and there is a (not necessarily injective) map $\phi:A \to G$ with $\phi(a)$ equal to the coset $\bar{a}\langle\langle R \rangle \rangle$, where $\bar{a}$ is the element of the free group $F(A)$ on $A$ corresponding to its generator $a$.
Then, to define a homomorphism $\psi:G \to Z$ for some other group $Z$, you start by making assignments $\psi(a)\in Z$ for the elements $a \in A$. There is no issue of well-definedness of $\psi$ at this stage. By the definition of free groups, these assignments induce a unique homomorphism $\bar{\psi}:F(A) \to Z$ with $\bar{\psi}(\bar{a}) = \psi(a)$ for all $a \in A$.
The theorem says that these assignments induce the required homomorphism $\psi:G \to Z$ with $\phi(\bar{a}\langle\langle R \rangle \rangle) = \psi(a)$ for all $a \in A$ if and only if $\bar{\psi}(r) = 1_G$ for all $r \in R$.
I think that if you use this more formal approach, then you will not have problems with the well-definedness of $\psi$.

Thank you, let me give this a go

Phew! It’s going to take me a while to type it all up, but I got it working and I have no doubts about the conclusion. Thanks for the help :)
